# PHP banned words filter error on preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am having some trouble with this code. It returns: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ‘\’

Also, I was wondering how I might call this code as a php include file on the form when submitted so it runs the checks on the submitted textarea BEFORE inserting the text in the db. I know this is a separate question completely and I will likely end up posting it as such. Maybe just the basic concept as an answer to point me in the right direction.

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {

// Banned Words
$disallowedWords = array(
'badword'
);

// Find Banned Words

foreach ($disallowedWords as $word) {
if (preg_match("/\s+$word\s+/i", $entry)) {
die("The word '$word' is not allowed...");
}
}

// Match URLs

$urlRegex = '(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0
-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-
9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}
|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-
Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.
(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-
9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*';

// Search for URLs
if (preg_match($urlRegex, $entry)) {
die("URLs are not allowed...");
}

} 


<form name="startpost" action="" method="post">
<textarea rows="8" cols="90" name="text" rows="4" maxlength="300"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send post" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) with the delimiter.

Comment: You have forgotten the delimiters at the begining and at the end of the pattern.

Comment: You don't need `preg_match()` just to see if a string contains some word. That's overhead. Just use `strpos()`

Comment: You can use `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`

Comment: @bad_boy: here the "words" in question seem to be urls. Note too that strpos doesn't take account of word boundaries.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That was a dedication to `$disallowedWords`

Comment: @bad_boy: indeed, I haven't see that. However, consider the following sentence that will generate a false positive with strpos: `have you seen the movie "Riddick's Chronicle"?`